# Normal links with ExtJS callbacks?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

In a renderer I'm generating links, which I want to map to my controllers functions.
The ActionColumn does this with images somehow, but I don't get the mechanism behind it.
I would like to have buttons there, but ExtJS only lets me render strings in a grid.

[image: Here is an example with the links]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well.. the question is bit confused.

If you want to implement an ActionColumn with a callback, you will only have to implement the "handler" property which is the callback. See in http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Action

Real buttons aren't possible out of the box (and note: you should not), but you can render a button on your own.
I would suggest a bunch of icons (with the ActionColumn). No buttons required.